# Creating a New Variable Based on a Categorical Variable Already in the Dataset

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataset with a categorical variable `X` that takes the values `A`, `B`, or `C`.

I want to create a new variable `Y` that is

- 1, if `X` = `A`;
- 2, if `X` = `B`;
- 3, if `X` = `C`.

Here is what I have so far, and I know that it is incorrect.

```
if(X==A) {
  (Y = 1)
  }
else if(X==B) {
  (Y = 2)
  }
else {
  (Y = 3)
  }
```

I keep getting the error:

> Object 'Y' not found

How do I create the variable `Y` such that it can take on these new values based on the values of `X`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The up-votes to the question greatly puzzle me... so an answer is wanted for this question?

With loop-based method, as OP intended, is:

```
Y <- numeric(length(X))  ## initialize a numeric vector `Y`, of the same length of `X`
## loop through all elements of `X`, use `if-else` to allocate value for `Y`
for (i in seq_along(X)) {
  if (X[i] == "A") Y[i] <- 1
  else if (X[i] == "B") Y[i] <- 2
  else if (X[i] == "C") Y[i] <- 3
  }
```

The fully vectorized method, is

```
Y <- match(X, LETTERS[1:3])
```

Here, `LETTERS` are internal R constants for capital letters. There are few constants in R, and you can get them all by reading documentation `?Constants`.

Answer (score 5):

Option 1: Take the numeric values of the factor.

```
X
# [1] "B" "C" "A" "C" "A" "C" "B" "B" "A" "A"
c(factor(X))
# [1] 2 3 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 1
```

`c()` drops attributes, and is used for general fanciness.  `as.numeric()` might be more readable.

Option 2:  A lookup vector.

```
c(A = 1, B = 2, C = 3)[X]
# B C A C A C B B A A 
# 2 3 1 3 1 3 2 2 1 1
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(25)
X <- sample(LETTERS[1:3], 10, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you might want to consider `dplyr::recode` in the `tidyverse`. It's essentially a vectorized `switch` which seems to be what you want. Alternatively, you can use a second datatable and use a `dplyr::left_join` or `base::merge`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data = tribble(
    ~x, ~y,
    1, "A", 
    2, "A",
    4, "B",
    5, "C",
    7, "Z"
)

data %>% 
    mutate(
        new_var = recode(y, "A" = "first",
                            "B" = "second",
                            "C" = "third",
                            "Z" = "last")
    )
#> # A tibble: 5 X 3
#>       x     y new_var
#>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
#> 1     1     A   first
#> 2     2     A   first
#> 3     4     B  second
#> 4     5     C   third
#> 5     7     Z    last
```